# find the largest value in a cell

Tags: sql, qgis

how to get the largest value in each cell

```
D | Resultat/table2 | **greatest value**  
A |(1,2,3,4,5)    **|5**  
B |(1,2,3,4)      **|4**  
C |(1)            **|1**  
D |(1,2,3)        **|3**
```

I tried, but without success
[structure TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdNLg.jpg)
SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(ID1)
from tournee_reduite
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY MAX(ID1) desc;

in advance thank you for your help

Comment: Is the data stored in MySQL or other database? Can you include the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum value of a cell(column) use the MAX() function.

```
SELECT MAX(<numeric column>) 
FROM <table>;
GROUP BY <other column>
```

Comment: hello Navan K, when I entered the request, which you gave me, it falls into error, I ask myself the question if it would not come that it is not a STRING, I add a photo of the structure of the base

Comment: Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW tviewASSELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MR_TO_FC ;
GROUP BY ID: 1 - near "GROUP": syntax error

Comment: This is because you are creating a temporary view . When you use the clause AS , this error is raised . Check this question for more details : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186330/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-group-line-4-e-st-dwithin